# Buttons in html email signature not clickable

Tags: html, email, signature

I'm trying to use buttons to create a nice clickable interface for a banner below my email signature. It works when I run it before uploading, but after I've uploaded it it stops functioning.

```
    <button onclick="window.location.href = 'url';
       "style="background-color: #e1b53f;width: 136px;
        height: 75px;box-shadow:0px 2px 2px #d5ad4b;color: #000;
        margin:0px auto;padding: 0px;border-radius: 17px;
        font-family: 'garamond', palatino, serif;font-size: 17px;"><strong>View<br>Gulf 
        Coast<br>Homes</strong>
     </button>
```

I'm not sure if this an error in the code, or an issue with my email provider's html uploader.

Comment: Why not just use `<a></a>` tags? You can apply same style.

Comment: Good question, +1 and added an answer to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using javascript code to redirect generally javascript won't work in email templates

try changing your code by adding anchor tag as below.

> ```
> <a href="url">
>       <button style="background-color: #e1b53f;width: 136px;
>         height: 75px;box-shadow:0px 2px 2px #d5ad4b;color: #000;
>         margin:0px auto;padding: 0px;border-radius: 17px;
>         font-family: 'garamond', palatino, serif;font-size: 17px;">     
>         <strong>
>           View
>           <br/>Gulf Coast
>           <br/>Homes
>         </strong>
>       </button>
>     </a>
> ```

Comment: This did exactly what I was wanting to do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the e-mail application you are using is outlook (or phone), the tag button will not work (maybe this fact is also true for other e-mail applications). I suggest that you replace button for anchor tag and apply button appearance on it, as follows:

```
<a href="url"
   style="-webkit-appearance: button;
   -moz-appearance: button;
   appearance: button;   
   text-decoration: none; background-color: #e1b53f;width: 136px;
   height: 60px;box-shadow:0px 2px 2px #d5ad4b;color: #000;
   padding: 2px;border-radius: 17px;
   font-family: 'garamond', palatino, serif;font-size: 17px; text-align: center">
    <strong>
      View<br>Gulf Coast<br>Homes
    </strong>
</a>
```

Comment: This did activate the links but it took away that button feel, that I was looking for.  The <a > tags surrounding my button kept the original feel of the signature.  Thanks for the help!